# Initialize large two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to have **static** and **constant** two dimensional array inside a class. The array is relatively large, but I only want to initialize a few elements and others may be whatever compiler initializes them to.

For example, if a class is defined like:

```
class A {
public:
  static int const test[10][10];
};

int const A::test[10][10] = {
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

and I am interested only to initialize the elements marked with '7', how do I do this on the same elements, but with array of larger size, like array[1024][1024]?

Comment: Err... you seem to already have the correct solution.

Comment: How important is it that your data be const?

Comment: @Billy: But it will take him 789 years to code up a 1024 x 1024 array.

Comment: That's what scripts are for! Generate the freaking thing.

Comment: @C Johnson: Not very important for data to be const, but I will not change it...

Comment: @Nikolai: I could generate it with script, but it looks ugly in the code. I am looking for some more elegant solution...

Comment: @Nikolai - :) I'd love to see that code file. 1024 numbers wide... That would be one BIG code file. :)

Comment: @C Johnson: "1024 numbers wide". Compiler doesn't care about that. You could put entire array declaration into *.h file (just make sure it is included only once) so it won't scare away occasional code maintainer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Any part of an array which is initialized, that is beyond the initialization, is initialized to 0.  Hence:

```
int const A::test[10][10];           // uninitialized

int const A::test[10][10] = { {0} }; // all elements initialized to 0.

int const A::test[10][10] = {1,2};   // test[0][0] ==1, test[0][1]==2, rest==0
```

That means all you have to initialize is up to the last non-zero:

```
int const A::test[10][10] = { 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0}, 
  {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

It is not the best solution, but will save some work.

Comment: Also, for we don't need to write elements that don't interest us, like: 

int const A::test[10][10] = { {}, {}, {}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7}, {0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7}}

Comment: @Matthew empty initializer lists are a GNU extension.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to assign an int to const array after it's been initialized. So you will have to script it up:

And include your file this way:

```
class A {
public:
    static const int test[10][10];
};

const int A::test[10][10] = {
#include "data.inc" // points to the file generated by script.
};
```

Comment: This is a valid and pretty straight forward solution (esp. when considering off-line scripting to generate the header file). However, it may prove problematic when dealing with an embedded system with a tight memory. From some reason which is unclear to me, in all the compiler instances that I examined, the initialization of variables is done in run-time, rather than in load-time, which means that the array of initializer values will occupy extra space, on-top of the space allocated by the actual array variable itself.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally, a couple of hours after reading your question, I bumped into a possible solution while looking for something else in the book `"C - A Reference Manual" 5th ed., Harbison/Steele` (this is a fantastic C reference, by the way).

According to the book,

> C99 allows you to name the components of an aggregate (structs, union or array) to be initialized within an initializer list.

... and it gives an example:

```
int a1[5] = { [2]=100, [1]=3 }; /* eqv. to {0, 3, 100, 0, 0} */
```

So, depending on the compliance of your compiler and on the size of the non-zero elements in your array, you may be able to use this syntax to init your matrix efficiently. That said, the book doesn't give an example for 2D arrays. Unfortunately, I couldn't test this idea since MSVC++ 2005 doesn't seem to support C99.

Comment: GCC supports this only in C, not C++.

Comment: ysap, thanks but I only made it work with C and gcc as a compiler. In Visual Studio, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

When I do this, I use a method to read in data.  Generically, it looks like:

```
extern void ReadElements(string sFile, Matrix a)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double value;

    ifstream myInFile;

    myInFile.open(sFile, ifstream::in);
    while(!myInFile.eof())
    {
        myInFile >> x >> y >> value;
        a[x][y] = value;
    }

    myInFile.close();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the array only through accessor functions/macros and arrange the internal storage so, that the initialzed part goes first.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to hide non-const array somewhere, load it from file or resource, and then use const reference to access it. I.e.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int Array[1024][1024];

namespace DontTouch{
    Array arr;
    void initArray(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
                arr[i][j] = rand() & 0xff;
    }
}

const Array &arr = DontTouch::arr;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    DontTouch::initArray();

    //arr[4][4] = 0;//compiler error            
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
            printf(" 0x%02x", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will be (IMO) more readable than script-generated huge array.

You can do same thing with class that acts like 2D array (easy enough to write). Again - have non-const object somewhere, and use const reference to access the data. It should be easy to make non-const array completely invisibile outside of just one cpp.

Another way to do that is to generate array using script. If you think that big arrays are ugly, put entire thing into *.h file (make sure it is included in only one *.cpp file), so it won't scare people away. Compiler doesn't care what you write in your code as long as it is syntactically correct.

I don't think there are any other options.

Comment: Thanks, but here user needs to call DontTouch::initArray(), and I would like that this array is initialized automatically. Also, I want array to be static, const class member... Seems that only solution is the big generated array...

Comment: Matthew Murdock: "and I would like that this array is initialized automatically" make a class that initializes array from within construcor and put one static instance of that class somewhere. You'll get automatic initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It only takes four lines by using `std::fill_n`

```
using std::fill_n;
using std::begin;

fill_n(begin(test[3])+3, 4, 7);
fill_n(begin(test[4])+3, 4, 7);
fill_n(begin(test[5])+3, 4, 7);
fill_n(begin(test[6])+3, 4, 7);
```

Answer (score -5):

install R software, it's free ! 
then call function defined below with

> `writetable(data,"test","myfile.h")`

if data is your matrix then you're done

---

```
writetable<-function(data,varname="test",file="myFile.hpp"){
  cat('const static double CONST_array_',varname," [][] = { \n \t\t\t\t {",file=file,append=TRUE,sep='')
  for (j in 1:(dim(data)[2]-1)){
    for (i in 1:(dim(data)[1]-1) ){
      cat(data[i,j],',',file=file,append=TRUE)
    } 
    cat(data[dim(data)[1],j],'},\n \t\t\t\t\t{',file=file,append=TRUE)
  }
  for (i in 1:(dim(data)[1]-1) ){
    cat(data[i,dim(data)[2]],',',file=file,append=TRUE)
  } 
  cat(data[dim(data)[1],dim(data)[2]],'}\n }; \n',file=file,append=TRUE)
}
```