# Initialize two 2-d array to zero in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

My question is can we initialize 2-d array using `int a[10][10] = {{0}}`.

According to the top answer in [initialize-large-two-dimensional-array-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460074/initialize-large-two-dimensional-array-in-c),

> `int array [ROW][COLUMN] = {0};`
>   which means: "initialize the very first column in the first row to 0, and all other items as if they had static storage duration, ie set them to zero."

However, checking `C99 Standard 9899:TC3` and `C++11 Standard N4296`, I haven't found any official records supporting what was mentioned in this answer.

Besides, I do come across this issue when I try to solve the `LeetCode 474. Ones and Zeroes` problem with the following solution.

```
// To make question clear:
// It seems that "int dp[m + 1][n + 1] = {{0}}" cannot initilize all elem to 0
// "memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp)" is necessary to pass the OJ test. Any idea?

class Solution {
 public:
  // m : 0s, n : 1s
  int findMaxForm(vector<string>& strs, int m, int n) {
    int dp[m + 1][n + 1] = {{0}};
    // We will get "Wrong Answer" without memset() function below
    memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
    for (auto& str : strs) {
      auto cost = getCost(str);
      for (int i = 0; i + cost.first <= m; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j + cost.second <= n; ++j)
          dp[i][j] = std::max(dp[i + cost.first][j + cost.second] + 1,
              dp[i][j]);
    }
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j <= n; ++j)
        max = std::max(max, dp[i][j]);
    return max;
  }

 private:
  pair<int, int> getCost(const string& str) const {
    int cnts[] = {0, 0};
    for (char c : str) ++cnts[static_cast<char>(c == '1')];
    return {cnts[0], cnts[1]};
  }
};
```

Comment: N4296 is a draft in between C++14 and C++17, not "C++11 standard" as you claim.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.

Comment: the cast in `++cnts[static_cast<char>(c == '1')];` is redundant

Comment: M.M, thank you for your replay! IMHO, using static_cast in `++cnts[static_cast<char>(c == '1')];` could avoid implicit conversion. I think it's better program in this way.

Comment: It doesn't avoid any implicit conversion (there is still converstion from `char` to `size_t`) , and it makes the code harder to read for no reason. Implicit conversions are usually not a bad thing anyway. `++cnts[ c == '1' ];` is simpler

Comment: Is the conversion from `char` to `size_t`, instead of `int`? I think it did avoid the implicit conversion, introducing the explicit conversion.

Comment: Yes it is size_t. But even if it were int, not sure why you thought you avoided implicit conversion of char to int !

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Actually I wanna avoid the implicit conversion from `bool` to `size_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is C++ code.  Other questions and documents about C are irrelevant; C and C++ are different languages.

In Standard C++ , array dimensions must be known at compile-time. `int dp[m + 1][n + 1]` is an error (let alone trying to initialize it).

Possibly you're using a compiler that offers C++ VLA as a non-standard extension. In that case you are at the mercy of the particular compiler as to what the behaviour of the code will be, and what the behaviour of `={{0}}` on it might be. The C++ standard will not help.

My advice would be to avoid non-standard constructs, so that you retain the guarantees provided by the standards documents.

Comment: Thank you indeed! BTW, is the `static_cast` unnecessary? 'Cause I think it can avoid the implicit conversion.